# which method is first called when a xaml page is loaded in windows phone by default?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to know which method is first called by default when a xaml page is loaded in windows phone app and how can I change the method which has to be called first on load?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To directly answer your question: Initialize is the event you are looking for.

For more detailed information, Google is your friend:

Application lifecycle - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_applicationlifetimewp7lab_topic2.aspx

Controls and other objects should follow the standard event lifecycle:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754221.aspx

Comment: There is no `Initialized` event in `Page`, and `Loaded` is triggered before all components (of the xaml definition) are initialized.

Answer (score 12):

To automatically perform an action on page load, use this in your page constructor:-

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        //write logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also set the `Loaded` handler via xaml:

.xaml:

```
<Page
    ...
    Loaded="OnPageLoaded">
```

.xaml.cs:

```
private void OnPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```